# What are ways to debug Online Judge problems when no input case that causes Wrong Answer can be found?

Tags: c++, debugging

Now I am trying to solve the UVa problem 843:
https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=784

And here is the c++ code I tried for it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

void decode(int start, std::string& match);
bool canMatch(std::string& match, std::string w, std::string d);
bool hasConflict(std::string match);

int N;
std::vector<std::string> dict;      // Dictionary for allowed words
std::vector<std::string> words;     // List of words that is in a line for decrypting
std::set<std::string> exist;        // Set of `dict` for faster searching
std::set<std::string>::iterator it; // Iterator for the set
std::string temp;                   // Temp buffer for string
std::string cyphertext;             // Input line (encrypted)
bool done = false;                  // Flag for done decrypting

int main(){
    // Building dictionary, set used to find word faster
    std::cin >> N;
    for(int i = 0;i < N;++i){
        std::cin >> temp;
        if((it = exist.find(temp)) == exist.end()){
            dict.push_back(temp);
            exist.insert(temp);
        }
    }

    // Decrept each line
    scanf("%*c");
    while(getline(std::cin, cyphertext)){
        // For empty lines
        if(!cyphertext.length()){
            continue;
        }

        // Initialize
        std::string match(26, '*');
        done = false;

        // Parse the words in line into vector.
        words.clear();
        std::istringstream iss(cyphertext);
        while(iss >> temp){
            words.push_back(temp);
        }

        decode(0, match);

        // Debug
        // std::cout << "Result: ============================\n";
        // std::cout << "The matching is:\n";
        // std::cout << "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n";
        // std::cout << match << "\n";


        // Restore
        //std::cout << cyphertext << "\n";
        if(!done){
            match.assign(26, '*');
        }
        temp = "";
        for(int i = 0;i < cyphertext.length();++i){
            if(cyphertext[i] == ' '){
                temp += ' ';
            }
            else{
                temp += match[cyphertext[i] - 'a'];
            }
        }

        std::cout << temp << "\n"; 
    }

    return 0;
}

// Backtracking for decoding
void decode(int start, std::string& match){
    // Search from the first word
    std::string backupCypher = match;
    for(int i = 0;i < dict.size();++i){
        // std::cout << "Trying to decode word \"" << words[start] << "\"\n";
        match = backupCypher;
        if(dict[i].length() == words[start].length()){
            if(canMatch(match, words[start], dict[i])){
                if(start == words.size() - 1){
                    // std::cout << "End of sentence reached.\n";
                    // std::cout << "Current match:\n";
                    // std::cout << "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n";
                    // std::cout << match << "\n\n\n";
                    done = true;
                }
                else{
                    // std::cout << "Advancing to next word.\n";
                    // std::cout << "Current match:\n";
                    // std::cout << "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n";
                    // std::cout << match << "\n\n\n";
                    decode(start + 1, match);
                    if(done){
                        break;
                    }
                    match = backupCypher;
                }
            }
        }
        // Check if is done
        if(done){
            break;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Try matching the word d with the encrypted word w
bool canMatch(std::string& match, std::string w, std::string d){
    for(int i = 0;i < w.length();++i){
        if(match[w[i] - 'a'] == '*' || match[w[i] - 'a'] == d[i]){
            match[w[i] - 'a'] = d[i];
        }
        else{
            // std::cout << "Matching " << w[i] << " to " << d[i] << " Failed!\n";
            return false;
        }
    }
    if(hasConflict(match)){
        // std::cout << "Has conflict!\n";
        // std::cout << "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n";
        // std::cout << match << "\n";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool hasConflict(std::string match){
    bool used[26] = {false};
    std::sort(match.begin(), match.end());

    for(auto iter = match.begin();iter != match.end();++iter){
        if(used[*iter - 'a']){
            return true;
        }
        used[*iter - 'a'] = true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

which gets Wrong Answers.
After reading the article *How to debug my code*, 
I tried various suDebug inputs & self written inputs, 
Printed the values of the variables with those commended `std::cout`s,
and also building the following random input generator with testing on the uDebug site, which it always tells me all my output are correct.
I wonder if there is any other methods to debug **When I cannot find a input case that causes error**?

BTW, this is the input generator I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

int main(){
    char carr[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e',
                   'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 
                   'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 
                   'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 
                   'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
    int randNum;

    srand(time(NULL));
    std::cout << (randNum = rand() % 1000 + 1) << "\n";
    for(int i = 0;i < randNum;++i){
        int len = rand() % 16 + 1;
        std::string temp = "";
        for(int j = 0;j < len;++j){
            temp += carr[rand() % 26];
        }
        std::cout << temp << "\n";
    }

    for(int i = 0;i < 100;++i){
        std::string temp = "";
        int count = 0;
        do{
            ++count;
            int len = rand() % 16 + 1;
            for(int j = 0;j < len;++j){
                temp += carr[rand() % 26];
            }
            temp += " ";
        }while(rand() % 3 != 0 && count < 10);
        temp.pop_back();
        std::cout << temp << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks alot for helping.

---

Some input and outputs: (First given by the problem, second self-written.)

```
Input:
6
and
dick
jane
puff
spot
yertle
bjvg xsb hxsn xsb qymm xsb rqat xsb pnetfn
xxxx yyy zzzz www yyyy aaa bbbb ccc dddddd
Output:
dick and jane and puff and spot and yertle
**** *** **** *** **** *** **** *** ******
```

```
Input:
3
a
aa
aaa
z
zz
zzz
xx
cc
zzz xx c
zzz zz z
zzz xx zz z
(Empty Line)
xx
Output:
a
aa
aaa
aa
aa
*** ** *
aaa aa a
*** ** ** *
aa
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213205/discussion-on-question-by-uduru-what-are-ways-to-debug-online-judge-problems-whe).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turning on `-fsanitize=undefined`, I got a warning in `hasConflict` about an index out of bounds.

Indeed, it seems that `hasConflict` is sometimes passed strings containing `*`, in which case `used[*iter - 'a']` is outside the bounds of `bool used[26]`.

Not sure if that's the bug causing your failure, but it's certainly *a* bug.

Comment: `if (used[*iter - 'a']) {` -- This is a big bug.  There is absolutely no check if `*iter` is a lowercase character.  As a matter of fact, this is the worst way to do this.  Differing systems do not guarantee that lowercase characters are contiguous.  A `std::unordered_set<char> used;` would have been much safer.

Comment: @NateEldredge @PaulMcKenzie Thank you so much for your helps. I fixed the `scanf()` into `std::getline()`, and also add the `if(*iter == '*') continue;` checking. Now everything is smooth and finally I can get my sleep. Hope you all have a great day.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Could I ask that what is a differing system (or some sources)? It seems like google doesn't give anything with the term.

Comment: Google EBCDIC.  That is an encoding scheme where the lowercase characters are not contiguous.  [See this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC).  Note the table shows that lower case (and upper case) characters are not contiguous.